# Reassign Role in Multiple Cases

Tags: civicase, roles

What is the best way to reassign a case manger for multiple cases in CiviCase? For example, a case manager is leaving the organization and we need to reassign these cases to a new person. I can go to each case and reassign the case role, but I'm wondering if there's another way this can be done in a bulk process.

I'm thinking maybe one possibility is to place all the cases into a group and then adding a "new relationship" through Manage Groups. Then I guess disabling the previous relationships manually through the person's contact record.

Comment: Actually... "Add relationship" only applies to adding relationships to contacts and not case roles..

Comment: I would also appreciate the possibility to change a role/person for multiple cases. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so this is a bit of a workaround but it does the job.

1. In Drupal 7 Views or SearchKit, you can build a table that shows all case relationship that are active for a specific case manager (filter by case type and/or case relationship if needed). The columns you want are: case_id, contact a (the client), contact b (the old case manager), relationship type a-to-b, case start date, and case end date. You will want to export this list on a spreadsheet.
2. Next, assign an "End Date" to all the cases. This step will disable the active relationships and put an case "end date". If you are doing this in Drupal Views, get the "Views Bulk Operations VBO" module so you can modify the entities. Set active relationship = 0 and specify case end date.
3. Lastly, use the spreadsheet you downloaded to create a CSV import to CiviCRM. The columns should be something like: civicrm_relationship_type, case_id, contact_id_a, contact_id_b, and case_start_date. This allows you to make a new relationship for the client (client_id_a), for a specific case (case_id), to a new staff (contact_id_b) with a case start date (case_start_date).